# domain of a solution of y'=$y+2x^3sinhx\over x $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've solved this differential equation: y'=$y+2x^3sinhx\over x $,$y(-1)=0$ .

The domain of the solution is $(-oo,0)$?

Comment: what solution did you get?

Comment: What is making you thinking that this is the domain ? Please, tell us what is your solution.

Answer (score 0):

i have got by many calculations
$y(x)=2(x\cosh(1)+x^2\cosh(x)-x\sinh(1)-x\sinh(x))$

Answer (score 0):

y(x)=$-2exsinh(x)+2ex^2cosh(x)+2x\over e$